# Hello all i am posting the error which i have got in ubuntu 16.04 lts. While compiling

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, cmake-modules, geographic-lib

I am getting this error after giving the command cmake ..

Geographic lib already installed 1.45-2
cmake version - 3.5
boost version - 1.75

---

Boost 1.75 found.

Found Boost components:

date_time

Boost 1.75 found.

Found Boost components:

system;program_options

-- GeographicLib:

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):

Could NOT find GeographicLib (missing: GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIR
GeographicLib_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "1.45")

Call Stack (most recent call first):

/usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)

cmake/FindGeographicLib.cmake:27 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:63 (find_package)

---

What should be done for this error..?

Comment: It seems CMake still cannot find Geographic library. How did you install this library?

Comment: By these----------------sudo apt-get update  ,

sudo apt-get install geographiclib-tools

Comment: You need to install "development" package for being able to compile programs which uses the library. In case of geographic library it is [libgeographic-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgeographic-dev).

Comment: so it would be help me if i get the steps to install

Comment: In Ubuntu installing the packages is performed with `apt-get install`. E.g. `sudo apt-get install  libgeographic-dev`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ---- Got it sir , thank you